# Not getting sub date granularity in Google Sheets trend lines

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

My data is in variable increments, anywhere from six to eight hours apart like so:

```
1-1-2011 00:00:00     100  
1-2-2011 00:00:00     103  
1-3-2011 00:00:00     107  
1-4-2011 00:00:00     109  
1-4-2011 06:00:00     111  
1-4-2011 10:00:00     120  
1-4-2011 14:00:00     132  
1-4-2011 20:00:00     176  
1-5-2011 00:00:00     190  
1-5-2011 09:30:00     221  
1-5-2011 15:00:00     250  
1-5-2011 19:15:00     272  
etc...
```

When I build a trend line graph, every one of those entries on the 4th and 5th are stacked up in a horizontal line, then it jumps over to the 5th where they stack up again. End result is a stair step instead of a nice growth curve.

I built a [test spreadsheet](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0Ats8nSYkd8p-dGJLdDlScDIxVmR5b2ZydzA1YUdTM0E&hl=en&authkey=CKquhu4F) with the above test data. It of course works like a charm. Even after adding a second series.

Anyone have an idea what I might have broken that prevents me from getting sub date granularity on Google Sheet's trend line graphs?

Comment: Can you please include a screenshot of the graph that you have for the example above?

Comment: So it basically skips the hours in the X-axis?

Comment: Yes, exactly. No matter what the zoom level is.

Comment: @Lipis, just built a test sheet... works fine there. :(  reworded question as a result.

Comment: @cabbey most likely the data was wrong in your original file, you might had to change the format of the cells. In any case now it works..

Comment: I figured it was something like that, so I sat down and created a brand new file and re-entered the data by hand, one row at a time. That didn't help, but in the process I think I figured out what they're doing.

Comment: Your screen shot is no longer available.

Comment: sadly, skitch appears to have deleted it. it's not in my image history either. I'll see if I can reproduce it at some point for future question integrity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it appears to be caused by entering just enough data to tip the balance somehow. Throw this data into a sheet and apply a timeline chart. You'll get a nice curved line.

1/11/2011 00:00:00    1173
1/12/2011 00:00:00    1270
1/13/2011 00:00:00    1387
1/14/2011 00:00:00    1434
1/15/2011 00:00:00    1458
1/17/2011 00:00:00    1531
1/18/2011 00:00:00    1567
1/19/2011 00:00:00    1598
1/20/2011 00:00:00    1624
1/21/2011 12:14:00    1643
1/21/2011 12:30:00    1722
1/21/2011 13:30:00    1863
1/21/2011 14:00:00    1895
1/21/2011 16:45:00    1990
1/21/2011 19:23:00    2026
1/21/2011 23:59:59    2060
1/22/2011 11:00:00    2134
1/22/2011 19:46:00    2184
1/23/2011 14:00:00    2232

Now add this additional row:

1/10/2011 00:00:00    893

Boom, stair steps.

[image: sample]
(this is a screen shot of the test chart I linked to in the question.)

What's sad is that it appears to be an intentional data simplification. If the data in the cart bounces up and down within a day, then they don't seem to compress it. it's only if there is only growth or decline, then they compress it to day scoped as soon as you get enough data. It does not appear to be related to the total span of the data, as I did experiments with having the 1/10 data in place, and removing the 1/15 data returns you to a smooth curve.

Short of getting someone from Google to comment on this, I don't think we're going to get a better answer. :(

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Maybe you're using the wrong chart type for display this kind of information.</strike> When I selected `time line` from the `Charts` for the above data, I'm getting an interactive chart, exactly like the one they are using in [Google Finance](http://www.google.com/finance).

[image]

Comment: that's the one I'm using too.